# Django render without return?

Tags: django, return, render

I have situation where I have for loop inside my view function. And I need to calculate something and render content for each iteration. But render needs to be returned and thats why it makes only one iteration and then my view function ends. Is there any way how to bypass this? Thanks for reply. This is how I imagine how it should be.

```
for i in iterations:
    ...
    context = i.name
    render(request, template, {context: context})
return render(request, template, {context: context})
```

Comment: No `render` does not need to be returned, `render` only takes a template and generates a HTTP reponse. But you are free to do whatever you want with the result.

Comment: `render(..)` is after all just a function. It is a common pattern to return it, but you can store the result in a variable, to post-process it.

Comment: It is howver strange that you can not make a template that is capable to render *all* iterations.

Comment: Hmm thanks, I didnt realized that its creating HttpResponse and its definetly good to know. Now I see possibility to bypass it with js if I store all those iterations and then serve one every time when request come. So return HttpResponse and return render are the only ways to serve content? There is nothing that will be able to to do so without render?

Comment: @MiroslavSnopke: you need to return a `HttpResponse`, how that response is constructed is not relevant. So no, you can create hundreds of functions that each, in one way or another, return such object. Render simply invokes that constructor. You can also raise a `Http404` (or other) exceptions, that will be translated by Django into a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Why not create List/Dictionary for those iterated contexts and then do final render with return operation.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it and I will definetly try it. @Willem Van Onsem Thank you really much for your advices, it really extended my knowledge :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your loop you're overwriting the HTTP response and also the context, so that would not work anyway. The loop should create some array or list.

```
names = []
for i in iterations:
    ...
    names.append(i.name)

return render(request, template, {'names': names})
```

and in your template:

```
{% for name in names%} {{ name }} {% endfor %}
```

If your really want to render it first (for example if you want to add some html snippet), you could use `render_to_string`

```
rendered_str = []
for i in iterations:
    ...
    rendered_str.append(render_to_string('my_snippet.html', {'name': i.name}))
```

Comment: Havent tried it yet but I think I can mark this as solution because it answers my question.